# f(n) = o(g(n)) ve f(n) ≠ Ɵ(g(n))

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I'm trying to solve these problems as an example, but I'm stuck. If anyone has an idea, can they help?
Show the real relations asymptotically. Show that f (n) and g (n) can be or not.

```
a. f(n) = o(g(n)) and f(n) ≠ Ɵ(g(n))
b. f(n) = Ɵ(g(n)) and f(n)=o((n))
c. f(n) = Ɵ(g(n)) and f(n) ≠O(g(n))
d. f(n)= Ω (g(n)) and g(n)= Ω (h(n)) and h(n)= Ω (f(n)) if f(n)= Ɵ(h(n)) Here f, g and h are asymptotic positive functions.
```

Comment: I didn't understand your qustion. do you need an example of two function f, g that `f(n) = o(g(n)) and f(n) ≠ Ɵ(g(n))`?

Comment: it must meet both conditions.

Comment: Show that f (n) and g (n) can be or not.

Comment: A good first step is to find out the definitions of o, Theta, Omega, O and so on. Then you either find counter-examples or prove the statements using the definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take these functions:

a:

```
f(n) = x
g(n) = x^2
```

b isn't possible since the definition of `f(n)=o(g(n))` is `f(n)=O(g(n)) and f(n) ≠ Ɵ(g(n))`

c isn't possible since the definition of `f(n)=Ɵ(g(n))` is `f(n)=O(g(n)) and f(n)=Ω(g(n))`

Comment: a, b, c, d are all separate questions. can you help me with this?

Comment: I dont understand what do you need in d. can you explain it?